# avrdude: ser_open(): can't set com-state for "\\.\COM3"

Tags: arduino, windows-10, arduino-ide

I've seen other posts with the same error message, but couldn't find any solution that works for me. I'm using windows 10. I've done all the required steps, but the error still pops up.

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me was connecting the arduino, opening the serial monitor then loading the sketch.

Answer (score 1):

Just unplug the micro controller and plug it again.

Answer (score 0):

This error says: another app using COM3 port or on COM3 is not connected device.

---

You can try:

- Diconnect and connect arduino
- Close app using COM3 (if you know)
- Close serial monitor in arduino ide
- Check arduino connection
- Check port, check which port arduino is connected to

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `Serial.begin(9600)` in `void setup()`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with the port driver in Windows 11, to fix it just close Arduino Ide, and download this driver from windows 10:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KarCEulQWGrDdGeSev0uteJMSSP_D-Lw/view?usp=drive_link

and paste it in C:\Windows\System32\drivers

You're good to go, open your Ide and it should work